# JS no ejecuta el evento onclick

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo JS. Lo tengo ubicado dentro del head.

```
     <script>
          $(document).on('ready', funcPrincipal);
    
          function funcPrincipal()
          {
            $("#btnNuevoAlineamiento").on('click', funcNuevoAlineamiento);
    
          }
          function funcNuevoAlineamiento
{
$("#tablaAlineamientos")
.append
(
  $('<tr>')
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
          .append
          (
            $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'estrategias[]')
          )
      )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
          .append
          (
            $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'alineamientos[]')
          )
      )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>').addClass('text-center')
          .append
          (
            $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-primary').text('Guardar')
          )
          .append
          (
            $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
          )
      )
  );

}
      </script>
```

Y parte de mi HTML ES EL SIGUIENTE:

```
<label for="tablaAlineamientos">
              Agregar grupo familiar
              <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevoAlineamiento">Nuevo</div>
            </label>
            <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaAlineamientos">
                <tr>
                  <th>Estrategia</th>
                  <th>Alineamiento</th>
                  <th>Opciones</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="estrategias[]" value=""></td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="alineamientos[]"  value=""></td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                    <div class='btn btn-primary'>Guardar</div>
                    <div class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Que estoy haciendo mal????

Comment: Estas Usando Jquery?? o solo javaScript normal.. xq tu codigo que posteas es con Jquery

Comment: @WilsonFreddyAndiaAlborta Jquery....

Comment: Y que buscas hacer?  lo que muestras hasta ahora solo llama funciones que no hacen nada. Con un poco mas de información te podemos ayudar mas.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la parte donde importas la librería JQuery?

Comment: @CamiloGomez ahi edite la publicacion

Comment: @GustavoSánchez  **<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>** esta despues del </body>

Comment: Debería estar colocado dentro de `head`. Puedes intentarlo?

Comment: @gisela el problema que encontre es que no estas llamando la funcion `funcPrincipal`. Prueba esto:
`$(document).on('ready', funcPrincipal());`

Comment: @CamiloGomez no debería ser necesario. Se pasa la referencia de una función para que sea ejecutada cuando el evento se emita. No creo que ese sea el problema.

Comment: nono, lo intente en otra ocasion y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Te faltan los paréntesis al definir la función: `function funcNuevoAlineamiento`, debería ser `function funcNuevoAlineamiento()`. Siempre revisa la consola del navegador para saber si hay errores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás utilizando:

```
$(document).on("ready", funcPrincipal);
```

Pero la manera correcta de inicializar la función principal en JQuery es:

```
$(document).ready(funcPrincipal);

function funcPrincipal() { ... }
```

Aquí tienes un JSFiddle con el ejemplo completo funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/rznc1k9q/1

Toma en cuenta también que la importación de JQuery debe hacerse en el interior de los tags `<head>`, antes otros tags `<script>` que lo utilicen.

Comment: Ya esta el ID. abajo del label "Agregar grupo familiar".

Comment: Estás importando correctamente JQuery?

Comment: Entonces, lo que no me funciona es el .append 
Xq no me agrega una row.

Comment: Tal vez correspondería realizar una pregunta nueva, ya que la original ya tiene respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

tu funcion ready tambien puedes hacerlo con una función anonima prueba haciendolo de esta manera:

```js
<script>
          //Con Funcion Anonima
          $(document).ready(function(){
    
         
          
            $("#btnNuevoAlineamiento").on('click', funcNuevoAlineamiento);
    
          
          function funcNuevoAlineamiento
{
$("#tablaAlineamientos")
.append
(
  $('<tr>')
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
          .append
          (
            $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'estrategias[]')
          )
      )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
          .append
          (
            $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'alineamientos[]')
          )
      )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>').addClass('text-center')
          .append
          (
            $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-primary').text('Guardar')
          )
          .append
          (
            $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
          )
      )
  );

}
      </script>
```